# Concatenating file names into string for a function

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to concatenate a bunch of files into a string so I can use them for a function. 
As a test script I'm trying to do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for line in $(cat list.txt)
do
  x=" "
  A=$A$line$x
done

echo "$A"

mv "$A" ./stuff
```

but I'm getting the error:

```
 mv: cannot stat ‘x.dat y.dat z.dat ’: No such file or directory
```

but they are most definitely there

can I get some advice please?

Comment: Add some lines of list.txt to your question.

Comment: You could try `mv $A ./stuff` the quotes make the arguments appear as one filename to the mv function/binary ... not as isolated names.

Comment: Thanks @Dilettant that worked!

Comment: Great! If I were you, I would then accept @KedarMhaswade's answer. We often work in parallel for the general better. One types a comment, while the other provides an answer. Better two, than none ;-) Also note his comment on file names carrying themselves spaces "inside" ...

Comment: @yoshi2292 I am not too sure why you want to concatenate though. Why can't the `mv` command go in the `for` loop?

Comment: If your file names contain spaces, the proposed change won't work.  Instead, take a look at my answer below.

Comment: @KedarMhaswade this was just a little test script. The function I want to run doesnt take lists, the input has to be ./function -o outfile -i infile1 infile2 infile3....
but I have 100 files I need to input so I figured this would be easiest

Comment: thanks @Roshan that helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change the last line to `mv $A ./stuff`

That should work with files that do not have space in their names.

Comment: This wouldn't work in the cast that list.txt contains files with spaces.

Answer (score 1):

This solution will handle file names with spaces too.

```
#!/bin/bash
mapfile -t lines < list.txt
echo "${lines[@]}"
mv "${lines[@]}" ./stuff/
```

It reads the entire contents of the file into an array variable, displays the content of the entire array, and finally uses those values in the mv command

Comment: You need to use `mv "${lines[@]}" stuff/` to handle spaces correctly. Also, `mapfile` is only available in `bash` version 4 and later.

Comment: Interestingly, in this case the quotes aren't necessary.

Try this:

    `(echo File 1 ; echo File 2) > list; mapfile -t a < list; touch ${a[*]}; ls`

You'll see two files created, named "File 1" and "File 2"

Comment: I just tried it under bash v4.3.39, and got 3 files: "1", "2", and "File". Using double-quotes and `[@]` created just the two expected files. Do you have some non-default shell options (or IFS) set?

Comment: Ah, you're right.  I did have a non-standard IFS setting from an earlier experiment still lingering around.  I've edited my answer to include the proper expansion pattern as you suggested.

Comment: For earlier version of `bash` that doesn't support `mapfile`, you can simply use `while read line; do lines=("${lines[@]}" "$line"); done < list.txt`.